# How do I Union with an Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three separate tables, `bs_products`, `td_products`, and `fv_products`.

```
    SELECT 
bso.order_id, bso.order_num, bso.Salesman, bso.salesman_name, bso.date, bso.status,

bsp.product_id, bsp.product_branch, bsp.product_name, bsp.description, bsp.vatable, bsp.critical_stock,
bsp.quantity, bsp.sell_price, bsp.category_id, bsp.expiry_date, bsp.date, bsp.isEmpty, bsp.empties,

bss.sws_id, bss.sws_proname, bss.sws_isEmpty, bss.sws_category, bss.sws_unitprice, bss.sws_prodesc,
bss.sws_proexp, bss.sws_vat, bss.sws_number, bss.date, bss.sws_salesman, bss.sws_route, bss.sws_smname,
bss.sws_driver, bss.sws_plate, bss.sws_vehicle, bss.sws_load, bss.sws_productid, bss.sws_quantity
FROM bs_orders as bso INNER JOIN bs_products as bsp
INNER JOIN bs_sws as bss WHERE status = 'Completed' 
AND bso.date = '11/30/2016' 
AND bso.order_num = bss.sws_number 
AND bss.sws_productid = bsp.product_id 

UNION

SELECT 

tdo.order_id, tdo.order_num, tdo.Salesman, tdo.salesman_name, tdo.date, tdo.status,

tdp.product_id, tdp.product_branch, tdp.product_name, tdp.description, tdp.vatable, tdp.critical_stock,
tdp.quantity, tdp.sell_price, tdp.category_id, tdp.expiry_date, tdp.date, tdp.isEmpty, tdp.empties,

tds.sws_id, tds.sws_proname, tds.sws_isEmpty, tds.sws_category, tds.sws_unitprice, tds.sws_prodesc,
tds.sws_proexp, tds.sws_vat, tds.sws_number, tds.date, tds.sws_salesman, tds.sws_route, tds.sws_smname,
tds.sws_driver, tds.sws_plate, tds.sws_vehicle, tds.sws_load, tds.sws_productid, tds.sws_quantity

FROM td_orders as tdo INNER JOIN td_products as tdp
INNER JOIN td_sws as tds WHERE status = 'Completed' 
AND tdo.date = '11/30/2016' 
AND tdo.order_num = tds.sws_number 
AND tds.sws_productid = tdp.product_id

UNION

SELECT 

fvo.order_id, fvo.order_num, fvo.Salesman, fvo.salesman_name, fvo.date, fvo.status,

fvp.product_id, fvp.product_branch, fvp.product_name, fvp.description, fvp.vatable, fvp.critical_stock,
fvp.quantity, fvp.sell_price, fvp.category_id, fvp.expiry_date, fvp.date, fvp.isEmpty, fvp.empties,

fvs.sws_id, fvs.sws_proname, fvs.sws_isEmpty, fvs.sws_category, fvs.sws_unitprice, fvs.sws_prodesc,
fvs.sws_proexp, fvs.sws_vat, fvs.sws_number, fvs.date, fvs.sws_salesman, fvs.sws_route, fvs.sws_smname,
fvs.sws_driver, fvs.sws_plate, fvs.sws_vehicle, fvs.sws_load, fvs.sws_productid, fvs.sws_quantity

FROM fv_orders as fvo INNER JOIN fv_products as fvp
INNER JOIN fv_sws as fvs WHERE status = 'Completed' 
AND fvo.date = '11/30/2016' 
AND fvo.order_num = fvs.sws_number 
AND fvs.sws_productid = fvp.product_id
```

I tried running this on phpMyAdmin but it gives me an error of

> ## 1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and LIMIT

What is the correct query for this?

`_orders` Table

```
order_id (Primary)  int(11)                 
order_num           int(255)                    
Salesman            varchar(255)                    
salesman_name       varchar(255)                    
date                varchar(255)                
status              varchar(255)
```

`_products` Table

```
product_id (Primary)    int(11)                 
product_branch          varchar(255)                    
product_name            varchar(255)                    
description             varchar(255)                    
vatable                 tinyint(1)                  
critical_stock          int(11)             
quantity                int(11)                 
sell_price              double                  
category_id             int(11)                 
expiry_date             varchar(255)                    
date                    varchar(255)                    
isEmpty                 tinyint(1)                  
empties                 int(11)
```

`_sws` Table

```
sws_id (Primary)    int(11) No              
sws_proname             varchar(255)                    
sws_isEmpty             tinyint(1)                  
sws_category            int(11)                 
sws_unitprice           double                  
sws_prodesc             varchar(255)                    
sws_proexp              varchar(255)                    
sws_vat                tinyint(1)               
sws_number             int(255)                 
date                    varchar(255)                    
sws_salesman            varchar(255)            
sws_route   varchar(255)                    
sws_smname  varchar(255)                    
sws_driver  varchar(255)                    
sws_plate   varchar(255)                
sws_vehicle varchar(255)                    
sws_load        int(255)                
sws_productid   int(255)                    
sws_quantity    int(255)
```

Comment: have you look at that column of all union should be same

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal can you elaborate?

Comment: every select query having same count of columns ..@Odie

Comment: Specify your column name so that every select statement has the same number of column

Comment: UNION (by itself) forces every row to be unique, it simply is not going to help adding "select distinct" with each part of that query (once you sort out the columns)

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Please see edit. I have specified every column name into their respective tables

Answer (score 0):

When using UNION the number of columns that are in each subquery has to be the same and they have to be of the same data type.

You will need to adjust your query so that you are not using `*` but defining each column from each table.

See the following for more info:

- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

> There are some rules that you need to follow in order to use the UNION operator:
>
> - The number of columns appears in the corresponding SELECT statements must be equal.
> - The columns appear in the corresponding positions of each SELECT statement must have the same data type or, at least, convertible data type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-think you plan.

To do a union you need fields of the same names, and data types.  You can't simply select * and expect different tables to combine in a single result set.

You may need to change names or add dummy columns in different parts of the select to make it work.

If you post the table structures and field names people may be able to help you more.